# Django API: How to save/ save as project?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I am developing python backend for django web app.
In the application when user clicks on Save or Save As button then I should give pop up for confirmation which can be handled by frontend.
But in back end, when user opts to save the progress then I should save whatever progress they have made it on that application.

I have created API App and created other views (like Import CSV, Import Excel etc.)

This is whole different view where input for my function would be user click only. I have no idea on how to write this view.

Comment: You should share relevant code otherwise, it's nearly impossible to help.

Comment: @HigorRossato I have different views for different functionalities like Import dataset from CSV/ Excel/ RDBMS etc.
This is totally different function.

Comment: Can you make your question more specific? Tell us your best idea so far, and we can probably help you refine it.